# How to retrieve data that contains null value for some field in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, null, blackberry-jde

I am fetching rows of record from my sqlite table for blackberry application.But certain fields contain a null and i get a run time error of No stack trace at those field.How i can i continue fetching data irrespective of their null fields.
This is how my table looks

```
    Date        Bill  Receipt
    12/5/2012    50  
    16/4/2012    40    20
    1/6/2012     50    30
```

It gives me error for that third element of first row.

This is my code used for retrieving values

```
   grid.insert(new LabelField(r.getString(k))
```

continuously going through 3 for loops-one for row,one for column and one for each column of database table.
If anyone aware on a solution to this,please share.Thanks.

Comment: if(r.getString(k) != null){
grid.insert(new LabelField(r.getString(k)) 
}

Comment: The above code ignores the record with null value.Gives a run time error of data type mismatch.No stack trace.I would like to fetch all values including the null.Exactly as it is in the original table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Row.getObject() instead of Row.getString().  It will return 'null' for null values without throwing an exception.  If non-null, you can then do a type check, or just cast to String if you know it will always be of type string.